# error in your SQL syntax :Mysqli prepare with NOW()

Tags: php, mysql

```
function newpage($user_id,$page_title,$page_name,$page_content){
   if(!$stmt=$this->_conn->prepare("INSERT INTO pages(user_id,heading,name,content,created)values(?,?,?,?,NOW())")){
              echo $this->_conn->error;
   }
    $stmt->bind_param('isss',$user_id,$page_title,$page_name,$page_content);

    if(!$stmt->execute()){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

any problems in the query, used mysqli prepared statements, query contain NOW() for current time..in mysql db 'created' is changed to "sting(20)"

error is

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 1 Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param()
>   on boolean in C:\program data2\xampp\htdocs\engine\admin\cms.class.php
>   on line 15

**

> Solved...

**

Comment: in addition to the typo mentioned by @assen I would suggest it is better to  edit your table and add default `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` constraint on column `created` that way you need not specify `NOW()` from php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think ')' is missing

```
"INSERT INTO pages(user_id,heading,name,content,created)values(?,?,?,?,NOW())"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function newpage($user_id,$page_title,$page_name,$page_content){
    if(!$stmt=$this->_conn->prepare("INSERT INTO pages 
                                    (user_id,heading,name,content,created) 
                                    values (?,?,?,?,NOW())")) {
        echo $this->_conn->error;
    }

    $stmt->bind_param('isss',$user_id,$page_title,$page_name,$page_content);

    if(!$stmt->execute()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: (y) yes you missed closing brace.